# Pearl formation process: what is it called? How does it work?

Tags: marine-biology

I have heard a **pearl** is a *disease* of oysters.
Astonished by the statement, I searched a bit **[1]** and I discovered that  it is really a **protection** mechanism of the oyster.

I know this defense mechanism is not unique in nature. E.g. humans can isolate foreign bodies (this happens with not-extractable bullets), as well as bees *propolize* foreign bodies if they can't eject them.

What is the process, the ability of those organisms, called?

How does it works? E.g. how organisms recognize foreign bodies other than other things?

---

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearl

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nacre#Formation